# Jmeter- Test plan Functional test mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I tried to use Functional test mode in Jmeter. But not able to find any difference.
How to use Functional test mode in Jmeter ? Where it stores Response and Sampler data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your test using JMeter GUI - nowhere. The results are being kept in memory and can be visualized using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

---

According to the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults) you will only see the difference if:

1. You add the following line to *user.properties*

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   ```
2. Run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.xml
   ```

   - If `Functional Test Mode` will be unticked - only basic information will be stored in `result.xml` file (according to what is specified in [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) - see ), i.e.

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <testResults version="1.2">
     <httpSample t="298" it="0" lt="297" ct="54" ts="1540368444288" s="true" lb="HTTP Request" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="1597" sby="115" ng="1" na="1">
       <java.net.URL>http://example.com/</java.net.URL>
     </httpSample>

     </testResults>
     ```
   - If `Functional Test Mode` will be ticked - everything will be stored in `results.xml` file including request and response details:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <testResults version="1.2">
     <httpSample t="176" it="0" lt="176" ct="43" ts="1540368457253" s="true" lb="HTTP Request" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="1613" sby="115" ng="1" na="1">
       <responseData class="java.lang.String">&lt;!doctype html&gt;
     &lt;html&gt;
     &lt;head&gt;
         &lt;title&gt;Example Domain&lt;/title&gt;

         &lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot; /&gt;
         &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=utf-8&quot; /&gt;
         &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1&quot; /&gt;
         &lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
         body {
             background-color: #f0f0f2;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

         }
         div {
             width: 600px;
             margin: 5em auto;
             padding: 50px;
             background-color: #fff;
             border-radius: 1em;
         }
         a:link, a:visited {
             color: #38488f;
             text-decoration: none;
         }
         @media (max-width: 700px) {
             body {
                 background-color: #fff;
             }
             div {
                 width: auto;
                 margin: 0 auto;
                 border-radius: 0;
                 padding: 1em;
             }
         }
         &lt;/style&gt;    
     &lt;/head&gt;

     &lt;body&gt;
     &lt;div&gt;
         &lt;h1&gt;Example Domain&lt;/h1&gt;
         &lt;p&gt;This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
         domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.&lt;/p&gt;
         &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.iana.org/domains/example&quot;&gt;More information...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
     &lt;/div&gt;
     &lt;/body&gt;
     &lt;/html&gt;
     </responseData>
       <cookies class="java.lang.String"></cookies>
       <method class="java.lang.String">GET</method>
       <queryString class="java.lang.String"></queryString>
       <java.net.URL>http://example.com/</java.net.URL>
     </httpSample>

     </testResults>
     ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)